# Brightcove IOS Sdk Player without play/fullscren buttons

Tags: ios, video-player, brightcove

I'm using brigthcove video in the cloud dynamic from an iOS application using xcode, when I boot the player this is able to play a video correctly, but the play button, full screen and others show a question mark.

```
self.options = [[BCOVPUIPlayerViewOptions alloc] init];
self.options.presentingViewController = self;

self.controlsView= [BCOVPUIBasicControlView basicControlViewWithVODLayout];

self.playerView = [[BCOVPUIPlayerView alloc] initWithPlaybackController:self.playbackController options:self.options controlsView:self.controlsView ];
self.playerView.delegate = self;
self.playerView.frame = _videoContainer.bounds;
self.playerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[_videoContainer addSubview:self.playerView];
```

self.playerView.playbackController = self.playbackController;

I can change the icons associated with the buttons but I would like to use the ones that should bring the sdk directly.

```
BCOVPUIButton *b = self.playerView.controlsView.playbackButton;
[b setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconoapp-03"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Any sugestions?? THANKS anyway

**EDIT 1**: Added screenshot

[image: Screenshot player]

Comment: show the screen hot

Comment: u missed the image assets

Comment: Hi, i add to Assets.xcassets three elements copied from brigthcove example as you said (not with the framework by default) with this fixed names "Fullscreen Button",  "Pause Button" And "Play Button" and all works fine.

Comment: happy to hear ,